# Win7 scheduled task minute settings?

Tags: windows, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I must process a bat file for every minute but win7 scheduled task not allow per minute. Lowest 5 minutes. Can I set scheduled task win7 for per minute?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm`](http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm) for it.

i am no way affiliated with splinterware

or install cygwin and use cronjob instead